# Pandas output in Jupyter notebook need full data

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I want to see the full data in the jupyter notebook out cell. Not truncated with the  '...' thingy.

I want the full cell data

[image]

Comment: What happens if you cast that thing with `str()`? Are you sure the actual data _is_ in the dataframe?

Comment: Perhaps you could try getting the underlying NumPy array with `.values`

Answer (score 0):

I think it will always show you a truncated output. 
The best solution would be to use

`df.to_excel("filename.xlsx")`

it will generate a Excel sheet of the dataframe and then you can view it efficiently

Answer (score 0):

Pandas dataframe `__repr__` [just calls](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L645) `.to_string`, which accepts `max_rows` and `max_cols`. Here is what you need:

```
print(df.to_string(max_rows=float('inf'), max_cols=float('inf')))
```